# Magento narrow selection category "browse by" atributes stopped working

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Hi after doing some optimization one a magento site (1.4.2.3), I've noticed that that at the Category pages the "narrow the results" has disapeared. This function is very important because it allows the customer to search on brand, colour and type.

Double checked that categories are marked as anchor.

Recovered app/design/frontend/default/cust_template/layout/catalog.xml and app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml from a backup up where it was working ok.

Haven't touched /app/design/frontend/default/cust_template/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml nor app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

From catalog.xml;

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
```

Any one out there who can shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Remember that extensions have the ability to override your layout.xmls.  I would suggest disabling third-party extensions one by one with your caches completely disabled and seeing if it eventually returns.  Also try switching to the default Magento theme to see if it's possibly theme related.

Comment: Thanks for replying Axel, haven't installed any additional 3rd party extensions. Have an out of sync version on a development server which still is okay.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a silly question but when is  <catalog_category_default> and when is  <catalog_category_layered> being used?

Comment: If you look in the default catalog.xml that comes with Magento, you'll see that `catalog_category_layered` has the label `Catalog Category (Anchor)`.  It targets anchor categories, and the `catalog_category_default` targets non-anchor categories ;)

Comment: Finally fixed! It was a re-index of the layered navigation which was interrupted last time. Did a re-index now again and and tadaa, it appeared again.Thanks Axel

Comment: Ah yes.  The wonders and joys of Magento indexing!  Glad you figured it out.  I've learned with Magento, when in doubt...flush cache, reindex and seek blessings from the Magento Gods.